# how to get the text of div that was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is working nicely:

```
var saf = document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML
```

But is it fine?

This is not working:

```
var saf = document.getElementById(this).innerHTML
```

How to do that? This is the part of the code. Please help.

```
$('#group').click(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
    $(this).css('border-color', 'blue');
    var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById(this);

    $('#logout').text(MyDiv1.innerHTML);
```

Comment: Because 'this' has no relevance in the stand-alone line of code that you have written.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is legal its first case already the second what you are doing is trying to not possible unless the "this" is a string containing the identifier of the element

if this is just an element seek in himself, otherwise you need the identifcador the sought element

Answer (score 0):

If the event in which its called belongs to 'this' then it will work e.g.

```
document.getElementById("div1").click = function (){
console.log(this.innerHTML);
}
```

or something like that

Answer (score 0):

How about using the jQuery selector like:

```
<div id="div1" onclick="getContent()">
....
</div>
<script>
function getContent(){
    var saf = $('#div1').html();
}
</script>
```

Comment: thanx, but i have 3 div's with id="div1"... so i want to get the clicked one

Comment: Well the id should be a unique identifier for your element

Comment: What selecting by name or class?